# Provide periodically updated image from server without corruption

Tags: java, webserver

**Task**

I have a java web server which provides access to an image that is saved as file from a webcam via opencv / javafx and which is periodically (e. g. every second) updated.

**Problem**

If the image is updated on the server while it's being delivered to a client, the image on the client is of course incomplete and gets corrupted.

**Question**

What is the preferred way to guarantee that the image which the client reads is always delivered as a whole? Or at least the image shouldn't be corrupted.

I wouldn't mind having e. g. the upper image part from the previous image, the lower part from the new image if that would be a solution, but how would you approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two things for this:

1. You need to have control over the image creation, hence you read the image via JavaFx and store it on disk.
2. You control the delivery to the client.
   A servlet will help you to do that.

If you store the image on disk yourself, you could just block delivery to the client.
Using a [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) is perfectly suited for that.

You call its `writeLock.lock()` method before writing the image and `writeLock.unlock()` when you are finished.

For delivery to the client you use the same lock, but call readLock.lock()`method before sending the image to the client and`readLock.unlock()` when you are finished.

The Servlet itself is pretty simple, you just return the image read as a stream from the file with the read lock in place.
The lock will ensure that always a complete image is returned, no corrupted one.

If you do not store the image yourself on disk, it gets more tricky.
You could try to copy it on disk after you get notified of its creation, but that still is subject to a race condition.

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't that mean that the writing of the next image is delayed until the slowest client got the file? Only after that the next image will be displayed for all the other clients that make new requests?

Comment: I choosed the ReentrantReadWriteLock because it allows any number of readers while a read lock is active and just one writer when the write lock is active.

So it will lock out all readers - say clients - while updating. But after the update it will allow all clients to access it in parallel.